# Azure B2C Linking Different Permissions to Users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a problem where individual user are registered to our application but with permission to see a single set of data. These are all setup as local accounts.

At the moment each user is associated with a single set of data.

We now need to be able to link different sets of data to the same user.

After or during login the user would be presented with the options that are linked to their account and it would remember this throughout their session.

We would also need to be able to add new permissions to an account through an API.

What is the best way of achieving this through Azure B2C ideally without using custom policies if possible.

Comment: What is "a single set of data"? Are you looking for a method which adds app based roles?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a page during the authentication journey (sign in) which reads the users access ability, and then allow the user to choose one of these options, and then issue that choice in the token, you will need a custom policy. I am assuming that this list could be different for each user ("options that are linked to their account").

If that list of options is stored on the user object, then it needs to be read from the user, and a dynamic radio box selection be presented to the user.

You need to create a comma delimited list and insert it [into a claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom#add-claims), if its already stored as comma delimited, or some other delimited list, then you are already good to go. Otherwise youll need to have B2C send the data to a [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) to build a comma delimited list.

That claim needs to be shown on the page after 'sign in' in a text box via B2C (hidden with CSS), where [javascript on your custom HTML page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout) (configured in B2C) builds a radio box from that list in the hidden text box.

Then the javascript needs to record the choice into another B2C rendered text box. You should then verify at B2C or via Rest api whether the submitted value was valid.

Then issue that value [into the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#outputclaims).